# MYSQL turn ORDER BY into comparable field

Tags: mysql

I have this `ORDER BY` clause for column `version`:

```
 version='D' ASC,
 version='R' ASC,
 version='Q' ASC,
 version NOT LIKE 'R-%' ASC,
 version!=0 ASC,
 version+0 DESC,
 version='M' ASC,
 version='P' ASC,
 version='C' ASC,
 version='0' ASC,
 SUBSTR(version, 3) + 0 DESC
```

This will return the 'correct' version when used in its context.
Is there a method I can drop it in to use it in a comparison context:

```
SELECT * FROM table
INNER JOIN table2
ON
METHOD(table.version) < METHOD(table2.version)
```

Comment: I think you may need to use a `CASE` expression with `ORDER BY` clause.